# How to generate reports with ReportNG when my TestNG application is executable jar file?

Tags: jar, testng, reportng

How to generate reports with ReportNG when my TestNG application is executable jar file

Cause when I turn my TestNG application into executable jar file reports are not generated.

I run java -classpath "test.jar:*"  with the same result.

Comment: What is happening if you execute it with testng? e.g. `java -classpath "test.jar:*" org.testng.TestNG testng1.xml`

Comment: I didn't try that.

Comment: But I want to do a small application for other manual testers to easily run it and get the reports.